# Applescript (via appscript) stops processing in loop

Tags: applescript, rb-appscript, sourceforge-appscript

The following ruby code automatically creates pages inside VoodooPad and adds meta tags to each page.

```
vp = app("VoodooPad.app")
doc = vp.open vpdoc

page_names = [@name]

if self.class.to_s.match('Stake::Stack')
    # Create the release notes page. Only run on parent stack
    notes = "#{@name} Release Notes"
    page_names.push notes
    doc.remove :with_name => notes
    doc.create :new => :page, :with_name => notes, :with_content => self.release_notes
end

# Create the settings page
settings = "#{@name} Settings"
page_names.push settings
doc.remove :with_name => settings
doc.create :new => :page, :with_name => settings, :with_content => self.to_md

page_names.each do |page_name|
    # Add the meta tags to the product page
    page = doc.pages[page_name]
    puts page_name
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "description"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "url"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "name"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "image"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "version"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "stacks_version"
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'version'          => @version_str}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'stacks_version'   => @stacks_version}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'subtitle'         => @subtitle}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'url'              => @info_url}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'image'            => @basename + '@128.png'}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'name'             => @name}
end
```

In the each block, the same meta tags are getting added to 3 pages. However, the tags are only getting added to 2 of the 3 pages. If we take the name of "Badges" as an example, here are my page names.

```
Badges
Badges Release Notes
Badges Settings
```

No matter the order of the array, the "Badges" page always gets the properly tagged. However, for the other 2 pages, which ever is processed first works. The other does not.

I thought maybe it was spaces in the page names. However, that does not matter. I get the same behavior. If you notice the code also dynamically creates both of these pages properly.

I have also tried adding a sleep, thinking it may be a timing thing. Nope.

I am stuck. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The page that I was adding tags to could not be the currently active page.

```
vp = app("VoodooPad.app")
doc = vp.open vpdoc

page_names = Array.new

if self.class.to_s.match('Stake::Stack')
    # Only the parent stack has a main page
    page_names.push @name

    # Create the release notes page. Only run on parent stack
    notes = "#{@name} Release Notes"
    page_names.push notes
    doc.remove :with_name => notes
    doc.create :new => :page, :with_name => notes, :with_content => self.release_notes
end

# Create the settings page
settings = "#{@name} Settings"
page_names.push settings
doc.remove :with_name => settings
doc.create :new => :page, :with_name => settings, :with_content => self.to_md

# Have to open to different page to ensure its not open when I add meta tags.
doc.open_page :with_name => 'index'

page_names.each do |page_name|
    # Add the meta tags to the product page
    page = doc.pages[page_name]
    puts page_name
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "description"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "url"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "name"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "image"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "version"
    page.remove_meta_record :with_key => "stacks_version"
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'version'          => @version_str}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'stacks_version'   => @stacks_version}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'subtitle'         => @subtitle}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'url'              => @info_url}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'image'            => "#{@basename}@128.png".downcase}
    page.add_meta_record :with_value => {'name'             => @name}
    # Open current page to ensure next page is not open or else cannot add tags
    doc.open_page :with_name => page_name
end
```